# REST design question multiple identifiers for a resource which need to be exposed to clients

Tags: http, rest

I would like to ask a design question about a REST HTTP API that I am exposing.

I have to sometimes access a widget with ID 3:

`http://ourserver/service/widgets/3`

Get widget with ID 3

But I also sometimes need to access a widget by it's SKU#.

Is it wrong to expose the same resource via 2 URLS?

BUt I need my clients to get a widget by either it's ID or it's SKU.

Which of the following is better?

- `http://ourserver/service/widgets/bysku/skyunumber`
- `http://ourserver/service/widgets/skyunumber?idtype=sku`

Again to repeat, I need my clients to be able to look up a widget in 2 different ways.  What is the best way to design the URLs?

Comment: I dunno...  seems irrelevant.  Do what works.

Comment: I'm asking a question about the proper design of a restful service. It is not irrelevant, but thanks for your input.

Comment: Why can't you pass the same URI twice?

Comment: I want my clients to be able to access the same resource via 2 different IDs which are associated with that resource. So some clients have 1 ID only to access it, and other clients have a different ID to access the same object.  There are 2 types of IDs.  Normal IDs and SKU#.

Comment: But are there two types of id's? (j/k)

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest considering the following:

```
GET http://ourserver/service/widgets?sku=34342323
=>
303 See Other
Location: http://ourserver/service/widgets/43

GET http://ourserver/service/widgets/43
```

By using a redirect, you can support any number of criteria to find widgets.  The key issue to consider is what happens when you start to enable caching.  If you return representations from multiple URLs you end up polluting the cache with multiple copies and it makes it much more difficult to invalidate the copies in the cache when you do updates.

Comment: Nice idea but I'll be calling into this API millions of times, it would create significant overhead for me.

Comment: @rest  The 303 response itself is cacheable, so you only incur one extra roundtrip per sku.

Comment: Similar solution described in "RESTful Web Services" P.84

Comment: @DarrelMiller, according to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, 303 MUST NOT be cached.  

This may change. According to http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-08#section-8.3.4, A 303 response SHOULD NOT be cached unless it is indicated as cacheable by Cache-Control or Expires header fields. 

Note, this is not yet adopted, and this language appears to have fallen off of the latest revision.

Comment: @benvolioT  Thanks for pointing this out.  I didn't realize that 2616 said 303 could not be cached.   It's even more interesting that this has changed in httpbis.